# Using a Managed Bean to transfer values between two Java EE files?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee

I have a Java EE class that gets information from a form and prints it out:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Response extends HttpServlet
{
String date = "0";

public void init() throws ServletException 
{
//Get Election Date from xml
   String initial = getInitParameter("electionDate");
    date = initial;
}

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
//Get values from form
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
String firstName=request.getParameter("firstname");  
String lastName=request.getParameter("lastname");  
String address=request.getParameter("address");  
String city=request.getParameter("city");  
String state=request.getParameter("state");  
String zip=request.getParameter("zip");  
String phone = request.getParameter("phone"); 
   String affil=request.getParameter("affil");

//Print Summary of Voter Registration
   out.println("<html>");
   out.println("<head><title>Registration Summary</title></head>");
   out.println("<body>");
   out.println("<p>Registration Summmary</p>"); 
   out.println("<p>First Name: " + firstName + "</p>");
   out.println("<p>Last Name: " + lastName + "</p>"); 
out.println("<p>Address : " + address + "</p>"); 
out.println("<p>City : " + city + "</p>");
out.println("<p>State : " + state + "</p>");
out.println("<p>Zip: " + zip + "</p>");
out.println("<p>Phone Number: " + phone + "</p>"); 
out.println("<p>Affiliation: " + affil + "</p>"); 
out.println("<p>Next Election Date: " + date + "</p></p>");

out.println("<p>Is the above information correct?</p>"); 
out.println("<button>Yes</button>"); 
out.println("<button>No</button>"); 

   out.println("</body></html>");
   out.close();
}
}
```

When you click the "No" button I want to send the values that's printed/stored (firstName, lastName, etc.) in the above Java EE file into the below one:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Confirmation extends HttpServlet
{
String date = "0";


void editForm()
{


//Print Summary of Voter Registration
   out.println("<html>");
   out.println("<head><</head>");
   out.println("<body><h1>Voter Registration Page</h1>");
   out.println("<p><p>Please fill out all information below to register as a voter.</p>"); 

    out.println(" <form method = 'post' action = 'confirmation'"
   out.println("First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>");
   out.println("Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" ><br>"); 
out.println("Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address"><br>"; 
out.println("City: <input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br>");
out.println("State: <input type="text" id="state" name="state"><br>");
out.println("Zip: <input type="text" id="zip"name="zip"><br>");
out.println("Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br><br>"); 
out.println("Affiliation:<br>"); 

out.println("<input type="radio" name="affil" value="Democrat">Democrat<br>");
out.println("<input type="radio" name="affil" value="Green Party">Green Party<br>");
out.println("<input type="radio" name="affil" value="Liberterian">Liberterian<br>);
out.println("<input type="radio" name="affil" value="Republican">Republican<br>");
out.println("<input type="radio" name="affil" value="Unafilliated">Unafiiliated<br><br>");
out.println("<input type="submit" value="Submit">");

   out.println("</form></body></html>");
   out.close();
}
}
```

However I want to use a Managed Bean with Java EE (and NOT using JSF) to do this. How do I do this correctly? What do I need to properly import?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You mean to another Servlet? Because i can see you are using only servlets here.. Are you using jsp?

Comment: Yes I'm only using Servlets. I am not using JSP.